# Foundry - Anvil mainnet fork EvmError: NotActivated

Tags: blockchain, solidity, anvil

I am using anvil (Foundry) to create a local fork and run my own transaction in it.

Anvil version: anvil 0.1.0 (0e72b71 2023-07-19T00:37:38.599511000Z)

The thing is when I run my transaction i am getting :  EvmError: NotActivated

```
│   ├─ [39] 0x73580081dA937844d57811b69A30378c1606EcF4::balanceOf(0xc40d6F37351622004e48FB8721919DC334ddD946) [staticcall]
│   │   └─ ← "EvmError: NotActivated"
│   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
└─ ← ()
```

For run the fork I am using this parameter :   --hardfork shanghai

To execute the transaction I am using cast in my local fork